# Boolean Check for searching duplicated value in binary tree

Tags: c++

my isdup function takes the root as the tree from main function and searching if there is duplicated value within the tree. So far all it returns true value if there is any duplicated value in root and any other places. However, if the tree has duplicated value in root->left and root->left-left, the function returns false and I have no idea why logic in the recursion function is wrong.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node* parent;
    node(int newdata):data(newdata){
        left = nullptr; right = nullptr; parent = nullptr;
    }
};

bool searchit(node*root, int value) {
    if (root == nullptr)
        return false;
    if (value == root->data) return true;
    bool left = searchit(root->left, value);
    if (left) return true;
    bool right= searchit(root->right, value);
    return right;

}

bool isdup(node* root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        if (searchit(root->left, root->data))return true;
        if (searchit(root->right, root->data))return true;
        return isdup(root->left) || isdup(root->right);
    }
    else return false;
}


void print(node *root) {
    if(root!=nullptr){
    print(root->left);
    cout << root->data;
    print(root->right);
    }
}


int main() {
    node* root = new node(1);
    root->left = new node(2);
    root->right = new node(4);
    root->left->left = new node(4);
    print(root);
    cout << endl;
    if (isdup(root))cout << "Yes, there is duplicated value in the tree" << endl;
    else cout << "no, there is no duplicated value in the tree" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through this?

Answer (score 0):

In isdup, the first 2 searchit's will not return anything (the first time) because it looks for root data...
Then left and right acts as roots, and below the left (as) root no duplicates are to be found, as is the case below the right (as) root. The left and right roots are really unrelated